# Chrome Extension - Prevent options page from being discarded

Tags: google-chrome-extension, background, garbage-collection

With Chrome 46 the Google introduced [automatic tab discarding feature](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/tab-discarding). After awhile this feature became enabled by default. I'm developing an chrome extension and running a long-running process in options page, not background page. After some time this tab consumes moderate amount of memory and if it is not active it becomes discarded. How to prevent the options page from being discarded? If it is not possible to do using options page, how to accomplish it using backgroung page, how to make background page run forever and never discard?

Comment: Use `"persistent":true` in `"background"` key in the extension's manifest to make the background page permanent.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update

Comment: @DanielHerr, It wouldn't take much to make that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your options page is not using user input, it would be better to run the process in the background page. If you want to do it in the background, you can mark it as persistent, but persistent is the current default.

manifest.json

```
"background": { "scripts": [ "background.js" ], "persistent": true }
```

However, it is possible to prevent tabs from being auto discarded.

options.js

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function({ id }) {
 chrome.tabs.update(id, { autoDiscardable: false })
})
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs